# Module has no exported member 'Control' - Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm updating my project from Ionic Beta to Ionic RC, and I'm getting this error:

```
Module '"/home/xxx/Desktop/myApp/node_modules/@angular/common/index"' has no exported member 'Control' 
L1:  import {Control} from '@angular/common';
```

How do I import correctly `Control` member ?

Can you provide a page (if it exists) with Ionic RC members and their relative module?

For your information when I do `ionic info` I get:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.36
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 
Node Version: v4.2.6
```

Comment: What control are you trying to import?  As far as I know, Angular 2 does not have (and hasn't for quite some time) had a `Control` export.  As far as what is in `@angular/common` the API docs on their site has the information [/common specifically](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything related to forms will be in `@anuglar/forms`.

First need to `@NgModule.imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule ]` to get all the directives.

Instead of `Control`, you'll want to use `FormControl`. There's also `FormGroup`, and also `FormBuilder` that you can inject.

For the directives, you can either use `[formControl]` to handle individual `FormControl`. Or you can use `formControlName` along with `FormGroup`

For example

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input type="text" formControlName="firstName"  />
      <input type="text" formControlName="lastName"  />
    </form>
  `
}) 
class SomeComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(builder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = builder.group({
      'firstName': '',
      'lastName': ''
    })
  }
}
```

**See Also:**

- [Dynamic Forms Cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html) form more in-depth discussion and examples.